# Is there "continuous" versioning?

Tags: version-control, collaboration, continuous

Is there any revision control/subversioning system out there that allows you/ a group to check out the latest version, and then collaboratively work on it simultaneously? I am thinking something similar to how [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/) works in terms of allowing everyone to edit a document at the same time, but more "repository" based if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried looking at any of [Distributed Version Control Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software), like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)? What problem are you trying to tackle that can't be handled by a 'normal' (D)VCS setup?

Comment: I suppose the problem I am trying to solve is similar to pair programming. Multiple people working on the same project at the same time. I do not know if it would be beneficial, I was just wondering if it has been tried

Answer (score 0):

svn and bzr, and probably cvs, all allow this, however the conflict resolution can always be tedious if you're all working on the same part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [Etherpad](https://github.com/ether/pad)?